# pandas dataframe: round column and interpolate the rest

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd dataframe with the following structure:

```
INDEX    X      Y       Z
    0    3.05   89.23   1.28
    1    11.54  89.63   1.27
    2    3.05   45.71   1.23
    3    7.70   79.36   1.25
    4    7.95   46.74   1.21
    ...  ...    ...     ... 
    96   6.64   45.00   1.21
    97   8.00   47.00   1.23
    98   6.64   53.00   1.24
    99   4.49   53.00   1.26
    100  10.76  84.00   1.22
```

I want to round the values in column 'Z' to the nearest 0.5 (e.g: 1.21 -> 1.0, 1.26 -> 1.5).
I know how to do that, but I also want to have all the values of columns 'X' and 'Y' in each row interpolate or extrapolate to their corresponding values (based on the rounding of their 'Z' counterpart).

Is there any easy or already implmented way to do this? It *seems* like there should be, but I haven't been able to find a way.

Comment: There's a lot of ambiguity in your explanation. Please post the expected output for the provided data frame

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what you are trying to achieve. It would also be helpful, if you could extend your explanation on how you want to interpolate or extrapolate the X and Y values.